# Enterprise Library 6.0 Logging TraceListner

Tags: enterprise-library-6

We are getting lots of log file with GUID prefix and files size 0KB only. how can we resolve this issues.

I tried to increase the file size and file max limit, but issue still exists.

Comment: We can't guess what your code does, or how logging is configured. Entlib was abandoned over a decade ago. By the time EntLib 6 was released people had already moved to logging libraries like log4net. Even people that did use EntLib won't remember its quirks

Comment: The problem isn't the log file size. I assume the application is using rolling file logging but somehow, the configuration is wrong. Entlib file logging didn't behave that way 10 years ago. The default file name would be some prefix and possibly a time component. Somehow, someone tried to use a GUID as part of the file name. Or someone added a custom log appender that has a bug

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question contains no information. I used EntLib 10 years ago. It doesn't behave like that. If the application worked fine for the last 10 years what changed? Reverse that change and it will probably work.